# Send ajax request from Javascript with xampp server to nodejs on port 3000

Tags: javascript, node.js, xampp

I have a php project that works fine with xampp. It runs well.

I now have to make this project work with NodeJS.

I was told to change the URL of the ajax (which has the URL to my php files) to

```
http://localhost:3000/folder/script
```

This works fine on Postman.

But my request goes always on fail(). I do not how to read the error. it shows undefined in the msj.

Here is what I got working fine in my local server but NOT working with the new URL:

```
$.ajax({
  data: { user: $userName, password: $password },
  datatype: "json",
  type: "get",
  url: "http://localhost:3000/user/loginUser", ///If i put here my php URL it works fine
})
  .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    let obj = JSON.parse(data);
    if (obj["Success"] == true) {
      window.location = "forms/firstPage.php";
    } else {
      swal({ text: obj["Message"], icon: "warning" });
    }
  })
  .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    swal({
      text: "ERROR: " + jqXHR.responseText + ": " + errorThrown.responseText,
    });
  });
```

Comment: it looks like you are new to node JS. Also, your question in its current form is not clear. my suggestion is to get a quick scan through this help doc on node JS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side its short and should help you understand the errors and post better questions.

Comment: Thank you!!! I will! Yes I'm new so, every help is useful :)